# Can I modify a program under GPL to use an incompatible library and publish the source?

Tags: licensing, gpl

The GPL disallows linking to a GPL-incompatible library. However, reading the GPL it seems to me this only applies to distribution of binaries.

So, is it allowed to

- modify a program under the GPL to use a GPL-incompatible library X (with calls to X, and modified build scripts), and
- publish my modified sources under the GPL?

---

As far as I can see, the requirements to publish the "complete corresponding machine-readable source code" only apply to binary distribution ([GPL 2 section 3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html#section3)). The part on modifying the source code ([section 2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html#section2)) never mentions anything about "completeness", it just says "work that you distribute or publish". So it seems using a proprietary library does not impact the distribution of the source code, but maybe I'm missing something.

I am interested in answers for both GPL 2 and GPL 3.